# pytest failing with No module named _pytest.resultlog

Tags: pytest

pytest failing with following error after installing `pytest-rerunfailures`

```
  File "/Users/dfd/.virtualenvs/sbase7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_rerunfailures.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _pytest.resultlog import ResultLog
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pytest.resultlog'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading pytest-rerunfailures fixed the issue

```
pip install --upgrade pytest-rerunfailures
```